# Using the mosquitto broker installed in google cloud 's instance

Tags: virtual-machine, google-cloud-storage, mqtt, broker, mosquitto

I have installed mosquitto broker in a Ubuntu VM Instance of Google Cloud . I can also see the broker running on port 1883 of the VM . The external IP of the VM is 130.211.173.165 . Now when i try to create a client for this broker by the command

```
 client.connect_async("130.211.173.165",1883,60)
```

I get an error message saying that the connection was actively refused by the remote IP .

I have also added a network firewall rule stating the below but nothing seems to work.

```
  Source Ranges:
             0.0.0.0/0
  Allowed Protocols or Ports:
             tcp:1883
```

Can someone help here ?

Comment: Make sure you can use it locally, to ensure it's setup properly - if it is continue to poke around at your firewall. If you are going through a router ensure that your router is forwarding that port to the mosquitto server too.

Comment: Thanks Preston  Let me try that